# Docker cannot change Status

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Hi is there any way to change docker status from Ready to Down?
I would like to change the status so as to remove the docker from the docker swarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way you can approach removing a node from docker swarm is to set the availability status of the chosen node to drain. Drain will prevent new tasks to be scheduled to the node and at the same time it will start to move all already scheduled/running tasks to other nodes. When this action is successful you will have a node in "maintenance/drain" mode which will be empty of all tasks.

You can achieve so with docker node update --availability drain [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_update/#options)

After node has been successfully drained you can simply remove it with docker node rm command [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_rm/)